# Unknown type name in c

Tags: c

My record.h file

```
#ifndef _RECORD_H
#define _RECORD_H

void run_status_window(Recording *recording);
void stop_rec_button_clicked_cb(GtkButton *button, gpointer data);
GtkWidget* status_window(Recording *recording); 

#endif
```

My .c file

```
#include "config.h
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "record.h"

extern GtkWidget* mute_button;
extern GtkWidget *app;
...
```

When I try to compile get this error:

```
error: unknown type name 'Recording'
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is `Recording` defined?  You need to include the header file that defines it.

Comment: Don't use `_RECORD_H`. Names beginning with one underscore, followed by a capital letter, are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the header file where `Recording` is defined.  Without the header file, the compiler has no idea what `Recording` is, so it gives you an error.

Also, you should not use the macro `_RECORD_H` for your header's include guard.  Names beginning with an underscore and a capital letter such as that (as well as names beginning with two underscores) are reserved by the compiler.  Instead, use something like `RECORD_H` or `RECORD_H_INCLUDED`.